# excel 2010 Type Conflict NumberFormat

Tags: c#, excel, excel-2010

I have a small program which creates Excel files from a database table, with Excel 2013 it works all fine, but i Need it now for Excel 2010 and now I get the following exception when i will add the "Format" to the NumberFormatLocal (`range.NumberFormatLocal = format;`)
The same exception will come when I use the `range.NumberFormat = format;`

Exception:

> Error message: System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException (0x80020005): Type Conflict. (Exception of HRESULT: 0x80020005 (DISP_E_TYPEMISMATCH))
>       At System.RuntimeType.ForwardCallToInvokeMember (String memberName, BindingFlags flags, ObjectTarget, Int32 [] aWrapperTypes, MessageData & msgData)

function:

```
if (chkWithValues.Checked && results.Item3.Any())
            {
                var rows = results.Item3.Count;
                var cols = results.Item3.Max(x => x.Count);
                object[,] values = new object[rows, cols];
                object[,] format = new object[rows, cols];

                //All returned items are inserted into the Excel file
                //Item2 contains the database types, Item3 the Values
                // pgMain shows the progress for the selected tables
                for (int j = 0; j < results.Item3.Count(); j++)
                {
                    int tmpNbr = 1;
                    SetMessage($"{selectedTableItem.TableName} {j} von {results.Item3.Count}", LogHelper.NotificationType.Information);
                    foreach (string value in results.Item3[j])
                    {
                        values[j, tmpNbr - 1] = Converter.Convert(results.Item2[tmpNbr - 1], value).ToString().Replace("'", "");
                        format[j, tmpNbr - 1] = ExcelColumnTypes.ConvertToExcelTypes(results.Item2[tmpNbr - 1]);
                        tmpNbr++;
                    }
                    pgMain.Maximum = results.Item3.Count();
                    pgMain.PerformStep();
                }
                Excel.Range range = xlWorksheet.Range["A3", GetExcelColumnName(cols) + (rows + 2)];
                SetMessage($"{results.Item3.Count * results.Item1.Count} Zellen werden formatiert....", LogHelper.NotificationType.Information);

                range.NumberFormatLocal = format;
                range.Value = values;
            }
```

My Excel Types:

```
public const string INT = "0";

    public const string TEXT = "@";
    public const string GENERAL = "General";
    public const string STANDARD = "Standard";

    public const string Date1 = "m/d/yyyy";
    public const string DATE2 = "TT.MM.JJJJ";
    public const string DATE3 = "T.M.JJ h:mm;@";
    public const string DATETIME = "d/m/yy h:mm;@";

    public const string DOUBLECO1 = "#.##0,00";
    public const string DOUBLECO2 = "0,00";

    public const string DOUBLEPO1 = "#0,##0.00";
    public const string DOUBLEPO2 = "0.00";

    public const string CUSTOM = "#,##000";

    public const string CURRENCYEU1 = "#,##0,00 _€";
    public const string CURRENCYEU2 = "#,##0 _€";
    public const string CURRENCYEU3 = "#,##0,00 €";

    public const string CURRENCYDO1 = "#,##0.00 _$";
    public const string CURRENCYDO2 = "#,##0 _$";
    public const string CURRENCYDO3 = "#,##0.00 $";

    public const string PERCENTAGE1 = "0.00%";
    public const string PERCENTAGE2 = "0.0%";
    public const string PERCENTAGE3 = "0%";
```

Update:

I've tried to use already the `public const string TEXT = "@";` as only format but the same error comes

Update 2 :

The error only occurs if the table has to many entrys. When I use for example a table with 1000 entrys its no problem and all works fine, if i use a table with 200.000 entrys the error occurs

Update 3:

[[image: NumberFormat and the value for one cell[1]]

I've tried to use only the standard format for testing, the following error occurs:

> Error message: System.OutOfMemoryException: Insufficient memory available to continue the program.

[image]

Comment: check the values, may be you are passing some incompatible values.

Comment: @viveknuna the Problem is that on this Point all cells are formatted and the object[,] format = new object[rows, cols] is filled

Comment: Each version of excel has a different Interop Library.  Make sure you are using correct version for excel 2010.

Comment: @jdweng I've checked it and its the correct interop version (version 14 is right, or not ?)

Comment: Version 14 is correct. (rows + 2).ToString() is needed.  Error could occur if Range is negative (rows = 0), or if you have a merged cells and you don;t access the upper left cell of the merged cells.

Comment: @jdweng  the problem is, that the error only occurs if the table has to many entrys. When I use for example a table with 1000 entrys its no problem and all works fine, if i use a table with 200.000 entrys the error occurs

Comment: Are you sure?  Type mismatches don't occur due to the number of entries.  They occur when the cell format doesn't match the data being written.

Comment: @jdweng i've updated the post with a screenshot from one cell, i think thats right or ?

Comment: It looks like now you are getting an out-of-memory Sometimes the workbook gets corrupted.Are creating a new workbook or working from an old workbook.Fix corruption you can fix problem by copying data to new workbook manually.A trick that sometimes works is to delete all rows and columns not used.In your case I would go to columns AA and select.Press Shift-CTRL Right arrow to select all unused columns and then right click and delete the unused columns.Repeat process going to last row 288910 and select.Press SHIFT-CTRL DOWN arrow and right click to delete unused rows.Save workbook.

Comment: @jdweng is there any possibility to do this automatically ? there are so many cells and rows that are not used, maybe it will help. for the corrupt workbook i have no idea because when the file get saved it works...the exception occured in the creating phase not when I will open the file

Comment: It only takes 30 seconds to do one worksheet.  I'm selecting all rows to right of used cells  and deleting.  Then selecting all rows below the used cells.  This was just meant as a test to see if it fixes issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could it be that you're passing something to Excel that it is interpreting as an integer that's too large for an integer data type in Excel 2010?
Maybe the row number for example? Test it by loading 32,760 rows then 32,770 as integers only go up to 32,767 in XL 2010. Worth a try :o)

Answer (score -2):

It depends on the file-format you use:

In Excel 2010, the maximum worksheet size is 1048576 rows by 16384 columns when using XLSX.

However You cannot generate this in the older XLS format, since it is still limited to 65,536 rows.

Comment: Check: Update 2 :

The error only occurs if the table has to many entrys. When I use for example a table with 1000 entrys its no problem and all works fine, if i use a table with 200.000 entrys the error occurs